# .map not working in the return of functional React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component using Hooks where I click a button to make API calls to the Hacker News API and push the results into an array. Then I set the state of "stories" to be that array full of stories.

I have a second function fired off by a button which console logs the state of "stories" and console.log's a .map returning each stories title. All of this works just fine.

If I attempt to use a .map in the return of the component it does not work. If I initalize the state of "stories" to be `["test", "test1", "test2"]` the .map works but as soon as I hit my button to set the state to be the array of stories the .map stops working. No error messages just the content goes away.

Here is where I import React and set the initial state, I've used Axios, Fetch and Wretch to make the API calls, all with the same results:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const axios = require('axios');
import wretch from "wretch"


function App () {
    const [stories, setStories] = useState(["test", "test2", "test3"]);
```

Here is the function that I fire off to hit the API andf set the state:

```
function call () {
        let storiesArr = [];
        fetch('http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
            .then ((res) => res.json())
            .then ((data) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    fetch(`http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${data[i]}.json`)
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((eachStory) => {
                        storiesArr.push(eachStory);
                    })
                }
            })
```

Here is a second function that I'm using to check that state was set with what I think it was and to make sure that a .map works on the state of "stories". This does work for me:

```
    function test () {
        console.log(stories);

       stories.map((each) => {
            return <p>{each.title}</p>
        })
    }
```

This is my return, the .map here does work with the initial state but does not once I set state to be the new array:

```
return (
           <>
                <h1 onClick={ () => call() } className="click">Fire off API calls</h1>
                <h1 onClick={ () => test() } className="click">Test state of stories/<br/>.map each title</h1>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Table</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                           {
                                stories.map((each, i) => {
                                    return <tr key={i}>
                                            <td>{each.title ? each.title : each}</td>
                                        </tr>
                            })
                           }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

           </>
        );
```

I am unable to figure out why the .map works at first, no longer works in the return, but does work in a function....

I would greatly appreciate any help any one can be.

Comment: Something may be wrong when you call `setStories`, can you show where it is called?

Comment: Agreed, you need to show the code where you use setStories.  The entire premise of this question revolves around it so I don't know why you left it out..

Comment: I can’t believe I did that. It’s the last thing in the call function,             Before the function closes but outside the .then’s. Sorry. I somehow missed it in my copy/pasting.   setStories(storiesArr)

Comment: @henryfrank fetch is async, throw the setStories inside of your last .then(), otherwise you will run into async issues

Comment: Thank you! That appears to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data fetching look a little messy, you know you can use Promise.all instead of pushing to an array and looping.

I have added a [check](https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted) to see if the component is still mounted before setting state.

```
const isMounted = useIsMounted();
//other code, I imagine useEfffect
function call() {
  fetch(
    'http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>
      Promise.all(
        data.map(item =>
          fetch(
            `http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${item}.json`
          ).then(res => res.json())
        )
      )
    )
    .then(
      result => isMounted.current && setStories(result)
    );
}
```

Also: http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json returns over 400 items, that will cause you to make over 400 requests for each item, I don't think hacker-news will appreciate that so maybe slice the result and or page it.

Comment: Those both sound like great suggestions. I really appreciate it. I’m going to give Promise.all a crack right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of an async processing issue than a setState one. Here is a handy all in one (simplified) example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// gets list of article ids
const getStoryList = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"
  );

  return await res.json();
};

// iterates over article list and returns a promise.all
const getStories = (articles, quantity) => {
  return Promise.all(
    articles.slice(0, quantity).map(async article => {
      const storyRes = await fetch(
        `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${article}.json`
      );

      return await storyRes.json();
    })
  );
};

// maps your response data
const formatStories = stories =>
  stories.map(({ by, id, url, title = "No Title" }) => ({
    id,
    title,
    url,
    by
  }));

function App() {
  const [stories, setStories] = useState([]);

  const call = async () => {
    // first get list of stories
    const res = await getStoryList();
    // then async request all of the individual articles
    // and push them into a group of promises
    const storiesArr = await getStories(res, 20);
    // then set your state.
    setStories(formatStories(storiesArr));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={call} className="click">
        Fire off API calls
      </button>

      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Table</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {stories.map(story => {
            return (
              <tr key={story.id}>
                <td>
                  <a href={story.url}>{story.title}</a> by {story.by}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I'm really going through this to understand it and put it into use. Thank you again, this is an excellent solution and I really appreciate the help.

Comment: :) I'm glad it was helpful, I remember banging my head on this concept for a while building out an app at work, it definitely gets frustrating. Not sure if helpful, but I often will build what I want with static elements to make sure my display stuff is right, and then start working in the async and business logic parts. It helps me get my head around what I'm trying to do so when I go to do the complex parts I already have an idea of how/when to trigger actions